# Why MySQL JDBC is not working in my Maven Project?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, mysql-workbench

JDBC worked fine in a non-maven project. When a user clicked the submit button after filling up the registration form, all the data was getting stored in the database but when I used JDBC in a Maven project, it throws the following error:-

> Cannot connect to MySQL server on google:3,306.
>
> Make sure that there is a MySQL server running on the machine/port you
>   are trying to connect to and that the machine this software is running
>   on is able to connect to this host/port (i.e. not firewalled). Also
>   make sure that the server has not been started with the
>   --skip-networking flag.

I have added all the necessary dependencies in the pom.xml file, still, don't know why I am getting this error.

Following is the pom.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>com.LIB</groupId>
  <artifactId>LiveInBliss</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.3.2</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bom</artifactId>
        <version>0.67.0-alpha</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>





    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>



  <dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>




  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
              <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
</plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.67</version>
</plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are likely using the wrong hostname, the wrong port or - **as the error suggests** - it is blocked by a firewall. Which is likely the case if you try to connect to a MySQL server on Google cloud.

Comment: Hi, The following is the jdbc url which I am using:- 
                                                           
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db_name?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false\", \"root\", \"mypassword                         The same worked in the non-maven project.

Comment: Then why does your error message say _"Cannot connect to MySQL server on google:3,306."_?

Comment: That's why I am asking this question. Can you recommend any solution for the same?